# Motorcycle type/class for the back of an RV

Tags: usa, motorcycles, national-parks, motor-homes

My partner and I are taking a RV trip through the U.S. and are planning to put a motorcycle on the back of the RV on the hitch.  We are looking for a motorcycle that:

- Is not too long as to stick out the sides of the RV (7'6''?)
- Easily gets two people a combined ~400 pounds up the fairly steep roads in the western national parks
- Fairly comfortable for occasional 1-2 hour trips
- Not too expensive
- Storage is not needed as we will drive it back to the RV at night

What class/type of Motorcycles would be good for such a trip?  What size engine would work for the Rocky Mountains?

Edit: I could have been more clear, there are [motorcycle lifts](https://www.google.com/search?q=motorcycle%20rv%20lift&espv=2&biw=1476&bih=798&tbm=isch&imgil=npjSHO-io8EB5M%253A%253BspYjLJ8WO_A0XM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fen.visonerv.com%25252Fcgi-bin%25252Fmd%25252FM10411%25252Fs1.pl&source=iu&pf=m&fir=npjSHO-io8EB5M%253A%252CspYjLJ8WO_A0XM%252C_&usg=__eLnuAQKBBFaZZhh9ITnf1IidX_U%3D&ved=0ahUKEwiZqJbT0LHKAhUW5mMKHf77ALcQyjcIQg&ei=EfKbVtnbBpbMjwP-94O4Cw#imgrc=V9ioPMVrbOxXYM%3A&usg=__eLnuAQKBBFaZZhh9ITnf1IidX_U%3D) and carriers on can attach to the back to the hitch on an RV.

Comment: Would you want to ride on dirt, asphalt or both?  That metric is critical to your decision.

Comment: As you are asking such a question, one has to wonder, do you have enough experience riding a motorcycle to negotiate steep mountain roads?

Comment: Not too expensive = how much $USD?

Comment: Asphalt only.  @Tom Hopefully after some classes and practice I should be ready by the time I hit the Rockies.

Comment: @gef05 The actual amount of USD is less of the issue that it being relatively cheap for a motorcycle (and cheap-ish looking?) so it is less likely to get stolen.  There will be times when it is vulnerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is not too long as to stick out the sides of the RV (7'6''?)

I am not sure what you mean by this, because - except for very few motocross bikes, you can't lift and place a bike on the back of the RV.  Please consider renting a motorcycle trailer; if you will be doing so - you may want to invest in a tarp or similar to protect the bike from the elements.

Now, as to your bike choice, for comfortable 2-up riding, you'll need a tourer-class bike, personally I would recommend a sport-tourer or similar.

These will have a slightly upright riding position. If you will be traversing paved roads, these bikes will be a great joy.

If you plan to go off-track or will be going up any kind of unpaved road or trek/trail - then I recommend a bike like with a bit more tracking and road clearance. Something like a Motto Guzzi Stelvio or similar.

Please note - riding a motorcycle on mountains and curved roads with a steep grade requires significant rider experience. If you are unfamiliar with the bike or the terrain, I would highly recommend renting it well in advance to familiarize yourself (and your passenger) with the bike.

Comment: There are motorcycle carriers for 2" slider hitches that can carry up to 600 pounds and have a "ramp" to load with.  But that is a lot of weight to carry if the slider is not exactly the same size as the receiver on the hitch.  Something the OP needs to pay equal attention to when buying one.